# Web2Py GET requests from Arduino (ESP8266WiFi)

Tags: arduino, get, web2py, esp8266

I'm using a NodeMCU and want to log data to my local Web2Py server.

The request: "http://minion.local:8000/ardulog/default/add/6476366/45643" works fine from the browser and returns a record id.

My Arduino can connect to my server but don't get any return data error or otherwise and nothing appears in my database.

```
// This will send the request to the server
samptime = millis();
rpm = (samptime + 333) % 96789;
String request = "10.0.0.244:8000/ardulog/default/add/"+String(samptime)+"/"+String(rpm)+" HTTP/1.1";
Serial.println("\ntrying: ");
Serial.println("GET " + request);
Serial.println("host: minion.local");
client.println("GET " + request);
client.println("host: minion.local");

// if there are incoming bytes available 
// from the server, read them and print them:
while (client.available()) {
  char c = client.read();
  Serial.print(c);
}

Serial.println("closing connection");
client.stop();
```

I've tried every variant I can think of but get only the following:

```
connecting to minion.local
[hostByName] request IP for: minion.local
[hostByName] Host: minion.local IP: 10.0.0.244
Requesting: 
GET 10.0.0.244:8000/ardulog/default/add/112725/16269 HTTP/1.1
host: minion.local
closing connection
wait 5 sec...
```

Why am I not reading anything retuned from the server?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! Though I was unsuccessful POSTing to Google Sheets, simply changing the word from GET to POST worked with Web2Py *without* sending any body data:

```
if(client.connect(host,port))  
  client.println("POST /ardulog/default/add/" + String(samptime)+ "/" + String(rpm) + " HTTP/1.1");
```

(still not receiving a result page from the server though)